# How do you copy an animated gif to clipboard from a keyboard?(iOS 8)

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, custom-keyboard

I'm making a custom keyboard in which you can copy an gif to clipboard when pressing a button.

I'm not getting to work so far. Even though I've tried the following

```
-(void)doWhenButtonPressed {


[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my.gif"];

}
```

Now it does not copy anything, which I think is kind of strange, because it does copy the image when i it with this line in a normal application. So what am i doing wrong?

PS: I have even checked that I can actually acces 'my.gif' by adding it programmatically to a button...
PPS: And the method -(void)doWhenButtonPressed is called as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally found the answer myself :)

You have to set "RequestsOpenAccess" to "YES" in your Info.plist. Then you can copy an image to clipboard!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo code in Swift 3.0.

```
let pb = UIPasteboard.general
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
if data != nil
{
 self.pb.setData(data!, forPasteboardType: kUTTypeGIF as String)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont really need the "RequestOpenAccess" to be enabled to actually copy paste into a UITextView. 
You just need to load your image into the UIPasteBoard general object and then you can paste it into a UITextView by long pressing and then choosing paste.

Comment: The question is about copying the image, not pasting it. As far as I know you need the RequestOpenAccess to be able to write from your keyboard to the pasteboard